# check if a pattern is in a list of words

Tags: python, list

I need an output that contains words that are exactly like a pattern - same letters in same spots only (and letters shouldn't show in the word at other places) and the same length
for example:

```
words = ['hatch','catch','match','chat','mates'] 
pattern = '_atc_
```

needed output:

```
['hatch','match']
```

I have tried to use nested for loops but it didn't work for a pattern that starts and ends with '_'

```
def filter_words_list(words, pattern):
relevant_words = []
for word in words:
    if len(word) == len(pattern):
        for i in range(len(word)):
            for j in range(len(pattern)):
                if word[i] != pattern[i]:
                    break
                if word[i] == pattern[i]:
                    relevant_words.append(word)
```

thx !

Comment: Just replace "_" with ".", then use your pattern as regular expression

Comment: what do you mean by replacing? the pattern is given

Comment: There is a standard way of writing patterns in python. Your pattern however is using "_" - which is another syntax. So you simply need to convert your syntax to the standard syntax, then you can use the standard pattern matching library see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html ... as shown in the way of the answer from Daniel Masejo

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

words = ['hatch','catch','match','chat','mates']
pattern = re.compile('[^atc]atc[^atc]')

result = list(filter(pattern.fullmatch, words))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['hatch', 'match']
```

The pattern `'[^atc]atc[^atc]'` matches everything that is not a or t or c (`[^atc]`) followed by `'atc'` and again everything that is not a or t or c.

As an alternative you could write your own matching function that will work with any given pattern:

```
from collections import Counter


def full_match(word, pattern='_atc_'):
    if len(pattern) != len(word):
        return False

    pattern_letter_counts = Counter(e for e in pattern if e != '_')  # count characters that are not wild card
    word_letter_counts = Counter(word) # count letters

    if any(count != word_letter_counts.get(ch, 0) for ch, count in pattern_letter_counts.items()):
        return False

    return all(p == w for p, w in zip(pattern, word) if p != '_')  # the word must match in all characters that are not wild card


words = ['hatch', 'catch', 'match', 'chat', 'mates']


result = list(filter(full_match, words))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['hatch', 'match']
```

**Further**

1. See the documentation on the built-in functions [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).
2. See the documentation on [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 1):

So you should use regex. and replace the underscore with '.' which means any single character.
so the input looks like:

```
words = ['hatch','catch','match','chat','mates'] 
pattern = '.atc.'
```

and the code is:

```
import re
def filter_words_list(words, pattern):
ret = []
for word in words:
    if(re.match(pattern,word)):ret.append(word)
return ret
```

Hopes tha helped